# How to split values from braces using SQL query

Tags: sql, split

I need a query to split values between braces separately.

My varchar value is

```
16(8),14(10)
```

I need to split as

```
16,14
```

I need only **16** and **14** value but not the values which is inside the `(8) (10)` braces

I have tried this query

```
select
  case 
    when charindex('(0-9)', OtherProduct) > 0
    then rtrim(left(OtherProduct, charindex('(0-9)', OtherProduct)-1))
    else OtherProduct end as OtherProduct
from dbo.rxnreactions where rsd='P=15(61),16(8),14(10)R=1,7S=9012'
```

is anyone can help me to split it.

Comment: Store them in their own columns, and you wouldn't have this problem ;)

Comment: You could use SQL CLR functions to use a regex? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to split by comma, then split by brackets, and at the end join into a single string

```
SELECT SplitByBrackets.val 
FROM dbo.StringSplit(N'16(8),14(10)',N',') SplitByComma
CROSS APPLY StringSplit(SplitByComma.val,N'(') SplitByBrackets
WHERE SplitByBrackets.id % 2 = 1
```

sample of the StringSplit is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringSplit]
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

[fiddle it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffdd4/3/0)